# How to manually on/off anti-aliasing of PIXI.Graphics object

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, pixi.js

Is there a way to on/off anti-aliasing of graphics objects manually? I am writing stock chart on top of PIXI.js and it has several shapes. If I set antialiasing property true when creating a renderer all chart shapes are antialiased (Straight shapes are also applied antialiased). Because of antialiased shapes, the chart becomes blurry. Therefore, if I have a way to on/off antialiasing each PIXI graphics objects manually I think chart will become sharp.

[Candle Chart - No need to be antialiased](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taGFP.png)

[Line Chart - need to be antialiased](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaGX2.png)

Would like to hear any advice on the subject.

Thanks in advance!﻿

Answer (score 0):

you can try to disable the overall anti-aliasing and use [FXAAFilter](http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.filters.FXAAFilter.html) /or even blur filter/ for the elements you want to be anti-aliased, Mind that if you have too many filters, it may not be very performant, although setting elements `filterArea` may help a bit in that regard